# Simple deform - Twist based on weight painted vertex group is not working as expected

Tags: modeling, modifiers, weight-painting, vertex-groups

Let's say I have a cylinder. I weight paint it using VertexWeightEdit, so I have nice gradient from top to bottom. Then I apply SimpleDeform modifier set to twist, and restrictions are set to vertex group. Sure, it does the twist, however I notice that certain vertices are pushed inwards. What does that happen? I can't figure it out. I guess I'm missing something important. I will appreciate any help.

[image]